# Remove Dimension from wp_get_attachment_image

Tags: custom-field, attachments, images

I am having some issue removing the width and height from my attachment images when using wp_get_attachment_image. This is what I am using to display the image

```
 <?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['slide_image_id'], true, 'full'); ?>
```

How it looks the the source code

```
 <img width="150" height="108" src="http://website:8888/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cupcakes-and-cosmetics-logo.png" class="attachment-1 size-1" alt="cupcakes-and-cosmetics-logo" />
```

I would like it to display like this

```
 <img src="http://website:8888/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cupcakes-and-cosmetics-logo.png" class="attachment-1 size-1" alt="cupcakes-and-cosmetics-logo" />
```

The image is getting pulled from an repeatable file field with an entry with an id of slide_image_id. I am have been looking around and have notice to use wp_get_attachment_image_url but when I use it with my above code the image does not display. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
 <?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['slide_image_id'], true, 'full'); ?>
```

Side note: $entry['slide_image_id'] is what is being used to call my repeatable file field.

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` returns a URL - not an image element.

Comment: What will be the best solution in what I am looking for @bosco

Comment: Wow, how annoying is it that every attribute of the img output is filterable with `add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes' ...` except only height and width are hard coded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your arguments for both [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) and [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) are in the wrong order - check the linked documentation for details. Additionally, `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` returns a URL - not an actual image element.

> Removing the `width` and `height` attributes from `<img>` elements is
>   inadvisable: if the layout of the page is in any way influenced by the
>   size of the image, the layout will "glitch" as soon as the CSS which
>   specifies the image's dimensions, or the image itself loads.

Unfortunately, the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function is currently (as of WordPress 4.4.1) hard-coded to output the `width` and `height` `<img>` attributes (see [ticket #14110](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14110)), so you'll need to build the image markup yourself. This can be done by taking cues from [`wp_get_attachment_image()`'s source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/media.php#L800):

```
<?php
  $attachment = get_post( $entry['slide_image_id'] );

  if( $attachment ) {
    $img_size_class = 'full';
    $img_atts = array(
      'src'   => wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['slide_image_id'], $img_size_class, false ),
      'class' => 'attachment-' . $img_size_class . ' size-' . $img_size_class,
      'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta( $entry['slide_image_id'], '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ) )
    );

    //If an 'alt' attribute was not specified, try to create one from attachment post data
    if( empty( $img_atts[ 'alt' ] ) )
      $img_atts[ 'alt' ] = trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt ));
    if( empty( $img_atts[ 'alt' ] ) )
      $img_atts[ 'alt' ] = trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ));

    $img_atts = apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', $img_atts, $attachment, $img_size_class );

    echo( '<img ' );
    foreach( $img_atts as $name => $value ) {
      echo( $name . '="' . $value . '" ';
    }
    echo( '/>' );
  }
?>
```

Comment: I did follow the link you sent me and was able to generate the image without  problem as well as using your solution. The only problem I am having how is with the alt tag. With the link you sent me an alt tag is not generated and with yours it is static (which is why I thought wp_get_attachment_image would be the best option). How would I generate an alt tag with the example you are displaying? @bosco

Comment: The issue turned out to be more complicated than I anticipated. Updated my answer to include the `<img>` attribute generation bits from `wp_get_attachment_image()` - though I left out the `srcset` and `sizes` parts used for responsive images. If these are needed, creating a function `get_sizeless_attachment_image()` would be advisable.

Comment: thank you this worked perfect. There was an error within the code do to a miss character  echo( $name . '="' . $value . '" '; should be       echo( $name . '="' . $value . '" ');. Thank you again for your help @bosco

Answer (score 12):

### Workaround

I did some core digging/testing and found a workaround through the `wp_constrain_dimensions` filter:

```
// Add filter to empty the height/width array
add_filter( 'wp_constrain_dimensions', '__return_empty_array' );
// Display image html
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['slide_image_id'], 'full', true );
// Remove filter again
remove_filter( 'wp_constrain_dimensions', '__return_empty_array' );
```

This seems to allow us to remove the *height* and *width* attributes from the generated image html of `wp_get_attachment_image()`, without getting out the reg-ex canons. We could also use the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` filter in a similar way to remove the *width*/*height* but keep the *url*.

### Notes

This workaround will remove the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes as well. But it's also possible to set the *srcset* and *sizes* attributes through the fourth `$attr` input argument.

As mentioned by @bosco, you've switched the *icon* and *size* input arguments in:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['slide_image_id'], true, 'full' );
```

Use this instead:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['slide_image_id'], 'full', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply used CSS for this one. It doesn't work in all scenario's, but often enough it will. Let's take a 300px x 300px image:

```
max-height: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
width: auto;
```

This constrains the dimensions of the image without losing its width to height ratio. Otherwise you can also use REGEX:

```
$html = preg_replace(array('/width="[^"]*"/', '/height="[^"]*"/'), '', $html);
```

These were some alternatives. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex approach**

After retrieving the raw image output that will include the width and height attributes, simply remove them with a regex replace of an empty string:

```
<?php
$raw_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['slide_image_id'], true, 'full');
$final_image = preg_replace('/(height|width)="\d*"\s/', "", $raw_image);
echo $final_image;
?>
```

In the future, it would be great if WordPress supplied a filter to get suppress these attributes.